# Which Jesus' movie is shown in this image?

Tags: life-of-jesus, identify-this

In many music videos in my language, there is a specific movie that clips are taken out of. I have looked in many places but I cannot pinpoint the specific movie. Here are a couple of images from the movie.

[image]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is from the famous Mel Gibson movie, "The Passion of the Christ". The scenes of Jesus' torture and crucifixion are available in the Youtube clip, [The Passion of Christ By His Blood](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCrCeboa_Kg) . The full movie can be viewed (for a fee) from a link in the description of the clip, or you can read more about the movie at wikipedia: [The Passion of the Christ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Passion_of_the_Christ).

Comment: Is it in English?

Comment: The dialog is in Aramaic.  There are English subtitles. Gibson did it that way deliberately, supposedly more authentic.